Adding more community-specific reasons for closing
I've noticed that many questions closed with "Other - add a comment" have the same reasons written in, and I'm interested to hear your opinions on whether they should be added as permanent community-specific reasons:
Not written in English
Example: Cómo conseguir ganar bitcoin
This is self-explanatory. Other sites (e.g. StackOverflow) already have this as a community-specific reason.
Not a question
Example: Request for a Quick Call to Learn about Current Pain points on Ordinal and Altcoins
I'm surprised this isn't among the standard reasons, as non-questions are presumably off-topic on every SE site. We get quite a lot of these, and although most of them are outright spam and deleted as such, some are benign enough to just get closed.
Bug report
Example: Bitcoin v23 is 10 times slower than v22 on macos for basic regtest tests
Most commonly Bitcoin Core bug reports. These usually include a question such as "What can I do about this?" or "Is this normal?" but are nevertheless off-topic here and should instead be raised in the specific project's issue tracker.
"Homework" / Very little effort
Example: How to verify signature of a given transaction data?
As more schools introduce courses on Bitcoin, we get an increasing amount of questions from people who basically ask us to do their homework for them without any effort on their part. Questions seeking help with a specific part of an assignment that they get stuck on are of course welcome. This might be partially coincident with "Needs more focus" but I'd still like to see it as a dedicated community-specific reason.

I'll be happy to propose/review the exact wording for any of the above if we agree to add them.

There was a discussion in 2021 about this here

And in 2014, it was discussed here.

I've added [tag:feature-request] to see if can get more items added to our existing list.

Unfortunately, each site is only allotted a maximum of 4 custom close reasons.  The ones we currently have are:

Personally, I would love to see more custom reasons added, but that would need consensus from Stack.
AskUbuntu had a similar meta question; it may be informative to look at that question.
We could modify the existing reasons, if our community can agree on what to change.

I see, thanks for the insight Hannah. I could perhaps see us merging #2 into #1 (or removing it completely since it falls under "opinion-based"). Will think about it and maybe create a new meta post.

Awesome ideas, I can get behind that

Yeah, alternatively it could be combined with the third, but just using "opinion based" seems like a good solution to free up the slot.
